# Unhandled promise rejection warning

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, promise

I made this function but I am getting `Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning`.
Tried refactoring but somehow I am not doing it right.

```
router.post('/authenticate', function (req, res) {
User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
    .select('username password')
    .exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!user) {
            res.json({success: false, message: 'Could not authenticate user'});
        } else if (user) {
            if (req.body.password) {
                var validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password);
            }
            else {
                res.status(200).json({success: false, message: 'Please provide password'})
            }
            if (!validPassword) {
                res.status(500).json({success: false, message: 'Could not authenticate password'});
            } else {
                var token = jwt.sign({username: user.username, email: user.email}, secret, {expiresIn: '24h'});
                res.json({success: true, message: 'User authenticated', token: token});
            }

        }

    });
});
```

Can you please tell me how should I refactor it to make it work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if (err) throw err;` definitely doesn't look right

Comment: FYI, your code has a path that can end up calling both `res.status(200).json(...)` and `res.statu(500).json(...)` which is not correct.  Also, `if (!user) {} else if (user) {}` can just be `if (!user) {} else {}`.  By definition, there's a `user` value if you get to the `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple solutions to help you debug:

First, set a promise library to give you the ability to .catch your errors.

[Adding promise library to mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)

Now you can do this:

```js
User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
    .select('username password')
    .exec((user) => {
      // do stuff
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      //error, its handled now!
    })
```

To see what the error is you can do this, but I remember reading somewhere that this isn't considered best practice. I have used it in the past just see where my error is coming from.

```js
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {

  console.log('unhandledRejection', error.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it simply adding a settings object containing "usePushEach: true".

```
new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String
}, {
  usePushEach: true
});
```